# Configuring ASP.NET Identity to use MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 to develop a web forms application. I selected Authentication: Individual user accounts. I want the application including ASP Identity to use MySQL.

I added references to MySql.Data, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, MySql.Web and have made the following changes to Web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="EkoPayMaster.Properties.Settings.EkoPayMasterConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=root;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=paymaster" />
</connectionStrings>

    <membership defaultProvider="MySqlMembershipProvider">
      <providers>         
        <clear />
        <add name="MySqlMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web" connectionStringName="EkoPayMasterConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" autogenerateschema="true" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>           
        <clear />
        <add type="MySql.Web.Security.MySqlProfileProvider, MySql.Web" name="MySqlProfileProvider" applicationName="/" connectionStringName="EkoPayMasterConnectionString" autogenerateschema="true" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MySqlRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="EkoPayMasterConnectionString" applicationName="/" name="MySqlRoleProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web" autogenerateschema="true" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"></remove>
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

When I run the application, I am able to register a user and log in. However, ASP Identity does not create the necessary user tables is the MySql database.

What do I need to do to have the application add the tables/user information into MySql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as I know, you must use exactly the same connection string name you gave in connectionStrings/add name in all your providers' connectionStringName attributes.

Comment: You are right. The issue was with the connection string name and not providing enough information for <DbProviderFactories>, i.e. Version etc.

Comment: You have sql script together with implementation which uses ADO.NET to talk with MySQL in this blog post http://blog.developers.ba/asp-net-identity-2-1-for-mysql/